# Why is pdflatex producing dvi output?

Tags: pdftex

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  I put the following into `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Me}
\title{My Test}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

And then I run `pdflatex test.tex` from my command line (I'm using TeX Live on Arch Linux).

I get the following on standard output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (preloaded f
ormat=pdflatex)                                                                      
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file test.aux.
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 224 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I don't see any relevant info in `test.log`.

Where do I go from here to debug this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Happy to participate.  If I've failed to follow any of the guidelines, please let me know and I'll improve the question.

Comment: Nothing obvious. (Well, not to me right now.) What command are you using to compile? Are you in the same directory as your `.tex` file? If so, `test.log` should be there.

Comment: No. Don't worry. That's the standard welcome text for cases where people pretty much have followed the guidelines ;). [Otherwise, you'd get a 'please add an MWE' or 'please complete your code' or something similarly specific.]

Comment: I'm in the same directory, using `pdflatex` (really a symlink to `pdftex`) to compile.  `test.log` is indeed created in the same folder, I just didn't see any information in there that looked relevant to the question.  In addition to the standard output info I quoted in the question, it talks about fonts, memory usage, and what I think are defined commands.

Comment: Is this a new install of TeX Live? (Either first time you've installed it or a new update.) Is there anything in `pacman.log` or did you get any errors when you installed? (Especially anything about failures to generate formats.) Do you have `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`? And/or `.log` with the same name in the same place?

Comment: Not sure this is necessary, but try installing `texlive-formatsextra`. By the way, I strongly recommend using upstream's installer rather than Arch's packages. (Or any distro's packages.) But I take it you want to stick to Arch's for now, at least.

Comment: Yeah, I've just installed it.  I have the `.fmt` and `.log` files, but no errors therein.  As an "obvious" workaround I'm just adding `-output-format=pdf` to all my commands.  But I'm hoping for an answer to my question ("How do I debug this?") because the behavior seems totally nuts to me and I have no clue which config files are affecting my programs.

Comment: What is the output on the terminal of the following command line? `pdflatex '\typeout{--\the\pdfoutput--}\stop'` If it contains `--0--`, then format creation went wrong.

Comment: Yup!  Contains `--0--`!  I'm having trouble googling what to do given the knowledge, but I'm pretty sure you've answered my question.  Mind turning it into an answer for me to accept?

Comment: If you look in the [install script](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/texlive.install?h=packages/texlive-core) you can find the instructions used to create the formats. You can then use those instructions to regenerate the formats. (Reinstalling the relevant package(s) should do the same thing.) I think that you wished to ping @egreg.

Comment: @purple_arrows Try doing `fmtutil-sys --all` (as a superuser) and check again the output.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr.  Looks like the install script includes the same `fmtutil-sys --all` line.  And, per @egreg, I reran that as superuser.  I still get the same issue (`--0--` in the output of the test code).  So I'm convinced my format generation is borked, not sure what to do with that.

Comment: You can use `fmtutil-sys --listcfg` to check which formats are available and which are enabled/disabled. Did you get any information from the output when you tried regenerating the formats?

Comment: @cfr The output on format regeneration was the same as before.  This is the relevant part, in case something jumps out: http://pastebin.com/AmPxCewn.  In particular, I've read through the config files listed at the top and cannot find anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, adding `\pdfoutput=1` to a (newly-created) `$TEXMFCONFIG/tex/generic/config/pdftexconfig.tex` and generating a local format file with `fmtutil` "works" for me.  But it sure doesn't feel like a complete answer to "how do I debug this?"

Comment: See what @egreg thinks...?

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat $(kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf)`? And also the output of `kpsewhich fmtutil.cnf`